# Purpose of anonymous modules in Agda

Tags: module, agda

Going at the root of Agda standard library, and issuing the following command:

```
grep -r "module _" . | wc -l
```

Yields the following result:

```
843
```

Whenever I encounter such anonymous modules (I assume that's what they are called), I quite cannot figure out what their purpose is, despite of their apparent ubiquity, nor how to use them because, by definition, I can't access their content using their name, although I assume this should be possible, otherwise their would be no point in even allowing them to be defined.

The wiki page:

https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/module-system.html#anonymous-modules

has a section called "anonymous modules" which is in fact empty.

**Could somebody explain what the purpose of anonymous modules is ?**

If possible, any example to emphasize the relevance of the definition of such modules, as well as how to use their content would be very much appreciated.

---

Here are the possible ideas I've come up with, but none of them seems completely satisfying:

1. They are a way to regroup thematically identical definitions inside an Agda file.
2. Their name is somehow infered by Agda when using the functions they provide.
3. Their content is only meant to be visible / used inside their englobing module (a bit like a `private` block).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous modules can be used to simplify a group of definitions which share some arguments. Example:

```
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Nat

<⇒¬≥ : ∀ {n m} → n < m → n ≥ m → ⊥
<⇒¬≥ = {!!}

<⇒> : ∀ {n m} → n < m → m > n
<⇒> = {!!}

module _ {n m} (p : n < m) where

  <⇒¬≥′ : n ≥ m → ⊥
  <⇒¬≥′ = {!!}

  <⇒>′ : m > n
  <⇒>′ = {!!}
```

Afaik this is the only use of anonymous modules. When the `module _` scope is closed, you can't refer to the module anymore, but you can refer to its definitions as if they hadn't been defined in a module at all (but with extra arguments instead).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I'm glad I finally know what this is all about, I am kind of disappointed, and feel like this is somewhat a hack, especially compared to other uses of underscores in Agda.  Being able to refer to the enclosed definitions without prefix and without opening the module beforehand feels weird. As a side note, I noticed that in the standard library, there is one occurence of such module without parameters, which thus has to be a mistake or somehow an aesthetic choice.

Comment: There's another use case: to open a module inside a `_` module locally (i.e. without opening the module for everything that goes after the `_` module).